# Display absolute page numbers

Tags: reactjs

There is a code that downloads and displays a book using the predefined list of chapters. The hierarchy looks like this: `Book -> Chapters -> Pages`. Actual download process happens inside chapter component (there is absolutely no way for me to change this because it will require rewriting around 5k lines of code). So, each chapter gets its own pages from the server.

The question is: how do I display absolute page numbers? Amount of pages in a chapter can be determined only after the download is finished.

E.g. chapter 1 contains pages, they will have numbers 1 to 10. Chapter 2 contains 20 pages, they should be numbered 11 to 30, not 1-20. Is there a react way to achieve this? I don't ask you to write code for me, just suggest a basic approach.

```
const Book = () => 
    <ChapterList>
        <Chapter number={1}><Chapter>
        <Chapter number={2}><Chapter>
        <Chapter number={3}><Chapter>
    </ChapterList>;

const Chapter = (number) =>
{
    const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        downloadPagesByChapterNumber(number, () => setPages);
    }, [])
    return <PageList> { pages.map((page)=><Page content={page} number={???}/> } <PageList>;
}
```

Comment: Can someone navigate to Chapter 2 without downloading Chapter 1? Also, 5K of code for a Chapter view sounds inefficient.

Comment: No navigation can happen until all the chapters are loaded. The code also includes DB queries and API, not just GUI.

Comment: So all Chapters will be download before even the first page view occurs?

Comment: Exactly. The load bar will disappear only after everything is downloaded.

Comment: You can add a context to ChapterList and update an Object with each key set to each chapter. Then, you can run a function to calculate the pages from the currently viewed chapter.

Comment: This will work for me, thanks. I'd accept this answer if it was not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a context to ChapterList and update an Object with each key set to each chapter. Then, you can run a function to calculate the pages from the currently viewed chapter.